# Why does my GitHub CocoaPod project list the build as invalid

Tags: ios, swift, travis-ci

I've just released my first cocoapod see [1](https://github.com/steve-cuzzort/ReadableConstraints), but can't get the build to say anything but "build invalid" - how do I show build passing?
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: The Xcode project builds for me. This question might need more detail -- where are you seeing "build invalid"?  show a screenshot.

Comment: This badge doesn't have any relation to CocoaPods. It will show "passing" when your build passes on TravisCI, and following the link of the badge, your setup of that is obviously flawed.

Comment: @Leo - How is it flawed?

Comment: Well Travis doesn't even know your repository exists and your username in the URL is wrong. So probably you also haven't created a Travis account and you haven't activated your repository there. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Do you have doc links?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Build invalid" box to see the specific error. For me, I was getting a "repository not found" error from Travis CI and did not have a .travis.yml file.